# How to view amount of reads and writes with Google Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I view the amount of reads and writes in real-time with Google Firebase?

That is, if my app reads something from Firebase how can I view the number of reads (getting incremented by 1 in this case) immediately after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you have like that for your real Firebase/Google Cloud project is going to be the logs in Cloud Logging and [Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/monitor-usage#cloud-monitoring). Within the Firebase console there is just the 30-day aggregated usage report.

Also see:

- [How to fetch number of reads and writes of Cloud Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64181864/how-to-fetch-number-of-reads-and-writes-of-cloud-firestore)
- [Firebase Firestore: How to monitor read document count by collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61112274/firebase-firestore-how-to-monitor-read-document-count-by-collection)
- [Discover which user is stressing firestore usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63969614/discover-which-user-is-stressing-firestore-usage)
  8 [Firestore billing & USage API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60720708/firestore-billing-usage-api)
- and the documentation on [monitoring Firestore usage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/monitor-usage)

Comment: Thanks Frank! What is the reason that we can't view any updates for today that happens regarding reads and writes on Firebase Console (on the project overview page)? I have to wait a day to see the reads and writes of yesterday and the days before for some reason but I can't use this to view the reads and writes of today in real-time.

Comment: Cloud Monitoring and Cloud Logging already show recent, and detailed usage data. If you think the Firebase console should also show that, consider [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report) for it.